# UIButton fixed background color when clicked in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, xib

I have been trying to make the buttons' background color fixed on a .xib. Like, default background is white but when the button is clicked it is going to be blue or black and it will remain that way until another button is clicked. 
I did most of the combinations with `UIControlState`, background color and image but nothing seems working. Background color changes for a sec and goes to default after a sec.

This is one of the combinations I tried

```
[self.theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-(void) slideAction:(UIButton *)myButton
{
    [self.theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Function works but it does not update the color. I don't know if it  the problem is related to .xib.
I appreciate of you can help me about the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: [myButton setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; //Change state and color as per your requirement

Comment: Check this post https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/ and this pod https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

on that button click put following code

```
-(void) slideAction:(UIButton *)myButton
{
    [self.theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

and put that code for another button click

```
-(void) AnotherButtonAction:(UIButton *)myButton
    {
        [self.theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this method:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(nullable UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code

  -(void)code:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        for (UIView* subView in self.view.subviews)
        {
            if ([subView isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            }
        }
    }

    -(IBAction)firstBtnAction:(id)sender
    {
        [self code:sender];
    }

    -(IBAction)secondBtnAction:(id)sender
    {
        [self code:sender];
    }

    -(IBAction)thirdBtnAction:(id)sender
    {
        [self code:sender];
    }

    -(IBAction)fourthBtnAction:(id)sender
    {
        [self code:sender];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `backgroundColor` is a property of `UIView`, as you know `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`.

This is important because then it is easier to understand why this property do not have States: A view do not have states. For some reason Apple decided to do dot extended the property behaviour for the buttons.

The method created in iOS to change the backgroundColor of UIButtons depending on the State is: `setBackgroundImage: forState:`. I know, that means you need an image for every state. A waste of space and memory.

To solve that problem I created a Category to handle `backgroundColor` States with `UIButtons`:
ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS

You can install the category as a [pod](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS/blob/master/README.md).

Or do it old school way: drag into your project the folder [/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS/tree/master/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS). That’s all.

Easy to use with **Objective-C**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;

...

[self.myButton bbc_backgroundColorNormal:[UIColor redColor]
                 backgroundColorSelected:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Even more easy to use with **Swift**:

```
import ButtonBackgroundColor

...

let myButton:UIButton = UIButton(type:.Custom)

myButton.bbc_backgroundColorNormal(UIColor.redColor(), backgroundColorSelected: UIColor.blueColor())
```

I recommend you import the pod with:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'ButtonBackgroundColor', '~> 1.0'
```

Using use_frameworks! in your Podfile makes easier to use your pods with Swift and objective-C.

**IMPORTANT**

[**I also wrote a Blog Post with more information.**](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/)